# Prove, if $X$ is compact and $Y$ is paracompact, then $X \times Y$ is paracompact (under product topology)

Tags: general-topology, product-space, paracompactness

I was wondering if what I've done is valid. I'm new to topology and relatively new to proof-based math other than linear algebra and a bit of one-dimensional calc. Any help would be appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynr74.png

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The image you’ve shared is quite difficult to read. MSE also [discourages asking questions in the form of images](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807). Please edit your question so that it can be understood without looking at the attached picture.

Comment: thank you for letting me know. i'll change it in a bit

Comment: No problem. You may find this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on MathJax helpful.

Comment: Show more generally that paracompactness is an inverse invariant of perfect maps, and the projection onto $X$ is a perfect map by Kuratowski's theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ve gone astray right at the start, I’m afraid: to show that $X\times Y$ is paracompact, you must start with an **arbitrary** open cover of $X\times Y$, not just one composed of basic open sets of the form $U\times V$ for $U\in\tau_X$ and $V\in\tau_Y$. (And there is no need to tinker with bases for the topologies of $X$, $Y$, and $X\times Y$.)

So let $\mathscr{U}$ be an open cover of $X\times Y$. For each $p=\langle x_p,y_p\rangle\in X\times Y$ there is a $U_p\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $p\in U_p$, and there are open sets $V_p$ in $X$ and $W_p$ in $Y$ such that $p\in V_p\times W_p\subseteq U_p$. Let $\mathscr{B}=\{V_p\times W_p:p\in X\times Y\}$; clearly $\mathscr{B}$ is a basic open refinement of $\mathscr{U}$. Any locally finite open refinement of $\mathscr{B}$ is automatically a locally finite open refinement of $\mathscr{U}$, so now we **can** work with nice basic open sets in the product.

We first use the compactness of $X$ to get an even nicer refinement of $\mathscr{B}$ by basic open sets in the product. Specifically, for each $y\in Y$ we’ll get a finite subcollection of $\mathscr{B}$ that covers the cross-section $X\times\{y\}$. For each $y\in Y$ let $\mathscr{B}_y=\{V_p:p_y=y\}$; $\mathscr{B}_y$ is an open cover of $X$, and $X$ is compact, so there is a finite $F_y\subseteq X$ such that $\{V_{\langle x,y\rangle}:x\in F_y\}$ covers $X$.

We now have $X\times\{y\}$ covered by the finite family $\{V_{\langle x,y\rangle}\times W_{\langle x,y\rangle}:x\in F_y\}$, where the sets $W_{\langle x,y\rangle}$ are all open nbhds of $y$ in $Y$. There are only finitely many of them, so their intersection is open: if we set $H_y=\bigcap_{x\in F_y}W_{\langle x,y\rangle}$, then $H_y$ is an open nbhd of $y$. Moreover, we can shrink each of the sets $V_{\langle x,y\rangle}\times W_{\langle x,y\rangle}$ for $x\in F_y$ down to $V_{\langle x,y\rangle}\times H_y$ and still cover $X\times\{y\}$; in fact,

$$\bigcup_{x\in F_y}(V_{\langle x,y\rangle}\times H_y)=X\times H_y\;.$$ And these shrunken sets still refine $\mathscr{U}$: $$V_{\langle x,y\rangle}\times H_y\subseteq V_{\langle x,y\rangle}\times W_{\langle x,y\rangle}\subseteq U_{\langle x,y\rangle}$$ for each $x\in F_y$.

We now use the paracompactness of $Y$. The open sets $H_y$ cover $Y$, so $\{H_y:y\in Y\}$ has a locally finite open refinement $\mathscr{G}$. For each $G\in \mathscr{G}$ there is a $y(G)\in Y$ such that $G\subseteq H_{y(G)}$. Let $\mathscr{R}_G=\{V_{\langle x,y(G)\rangle}\times G:x\in F_{y(G)}\}$; then $$\bigcup_{x\in F_{y(G)}}(V_{\langle x,y(G)\rangle}\times G)=X\times G\;,$$ and $$V_{\langle x,y(G)\rangle}\times G\subseteq V_{\langle x,y(G)\rangle}\times H_{y(G)}\subseteq V_{\langle x,y(G)\rangle}\times W_{\langle x,y(G)\rangle}\subseteq U_{\langle x,g(G)\rangle}\;,$$ so $\mathscr{R}=\bigcup_{G\in\mathscr{G}}\mathscr{R}_G$ is an open cover of $X\times Y$ refining $\mathscr{U}$.

All that remains is to show that $\mathscr{R}$ is locally finite, and I’ll leave it to you to finish that off. First verify that $\{X\times G:G\in\mathscr{G}\}$ is a locally finite cover of $X\times Y$, and then use the fact that each $\mathscr{R}_G$ is finite.

The steps that I used to get the sets $H_y$ are useful enough to have been pulled out as a separate result often known as the [tube lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_lemma), something that is well worth knowing.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment :) I'm a little bit confused about the first sentence about the arbitrary open cover. Shouldn't every element of such open cover, since it's open, be an arbitrary union of basic open sets of the form × for ∈ and ∈ ? I'll try to rewrite it in document format rather than image format to make it clearer as the previous commenter suggested. I have read the proof that uses the tube lemma, but just wanted to know if I could do it in the particular way I have laid out.

Comment: oh I see that my notation was wrong at the beginning defining an open cover. I'll fix that.

Comment: @Pete: There is also the problem that you start talking about a base $\mathscr{B}_X$ for $\tau_X$ without ever specifying what it is, not to mention that in general your $\mathscr{B}_X^d$ will be empty and hence certainly not a base. (I’m afraid that when I wrote my answer, I was thinking mostly in terms of getting down a correct argument and didn’t read yours as carefully as I ought to have done.)

Comment: ah i see. thank you!

Comment: @Pete: You’re welcome!